# Java is not able to locate shell script

Tags: java, maven, unix

I have a maven project. The java classes call a shell script. I have used `context.getInitParameter` like this:

```
String[] cmd = {context.getInitParameter("testabc"), value};
```

to call the shell scripts. In web.xml, I have put the path as:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>testabc</param-name>
        <param-value>/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/webapps/testMonitor/shellScript/Test.sh</param-value>
</context-param>
```

After deploying and executing I get the following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash","Test.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at com.ca.controller.ChefController.saveSchzScript(ChefController.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

The file is there. When I do a `vi` it displays the file, can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You open a new shell which does not have your environment settings, namely your path setting. And the current path usually is not in the search path. Try to call the shell script with the fully qualified path. Also check the script for execute permissions.